# Meaning and usage of "где бы"

Tags: значения

This is perhaps a use of **где** that I have yet to encounter; I simply can't work out the meaning of this sentence:

> Где бы смолчать, а он сейчас в драку.

Comment: [Где бы = Вместо того чтобы](http://phraseology.academic.ru/2353/%D0%93%D0%B4%D0%B5_%D0%B1%D1%8B)

Comment: Also "сейчас" in this sentence means rather "straight away" than "now".

Comment: I'd suggest a translation of this into better Russian as "Ему бы смолчать, а он сразу в драку (полез)".

Comment: Still, I think it ought to be "а он сразу в драку (лезет)", and not "...(полез)".  Although it seems that the past tense perfective verb *might* imply subjunctive mood.

Answer (score 4):

Here the words "**где бы смолчать**" is a subjunctive construct which actually means something like "anywhere it might be advisable to keep silent".  Translated from "proverbal" Russian, the entire sentence might be

> Смолчать бы где-то, а он тотчас же - в драку.

The order of words in Russian, as you probably know, is not predetermined, and here the particle **бы** is placed before the verb for giving the spoken phrase more fluency (compare to "смолчать бы", where you can hear a very hard pause between words).

Comment: Thank you Victor. I'm curious: is this a statement of general validity, or does it refer to one situation in the past?

Comment: It's general.  Besides, from "где-то" we conclude that it's not any specific situation, since the -то particle makes that pronoun undefined.

Comment: but it was где бы...

Comment: I was referring to the last sentence in my answer ("Смолчать бы где-то, а он тотчас же - в драку."), which I think is easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

```
Where he could keep silence, he would eagerly brawl
```

(I imagine there is better-styled version of "keep silent" in English)